# Make visitors adblock filter block non-ad elements

Tags: html, adblock

I have a Bitcoin faucet which is funded through ads. I would not like users to be able to claim if they have adblock enabled. Is it possible to attach something to a button to make adblock see it as an ad and block it, thereby stopping the user from claiming?

I would prefer it to be in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make the button "look" like an ad to AdBlock. For example, give it an id like `MainAd`; most installations of AdBlock use a list that will block this. Many users use [the EasyList rule set](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt), which has many examples of rules that will trigger the blocker.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/3rbej9vx/) (only works if you have AdBlock installed, of course).

Comment: Wow, that worked and was surprisingly easy. You just helped out a HTML noob big time thanks :)

P.s I would rep you but I need a rep of 15 first :(

Comment: I know I just had to wait for it to allow me it was saying I had to wait some time lol thanks.